# Как просто подключиться к Exchange (желательно на примере)

Tags: php, exchange

Здравствуйте. Использую одну строчку что бы получить фотографии из Exchange сервера, больше ничего не надо.

```
https://exchange.domen.local/ews/exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=mail@mail.ru&size=HR240x240
```

В данном случае он требует авторизации от пользователя, открывается фотография и всё ок. Как мне прописать пользователя/пароль к exchange, может даже сразу в этой строчке, что бы у пользователя не спрашивался логин/пароль. Начал смотреть мануал - ничего толком не понятно, надо библиотеку подключать (не понятно как), потом - не нашел функцию подключения, и главное не нашел нормального внятного  примера, только для С++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax

Стандартный синтакс URI схемы:

```
схема:[//[логин[:пароль]@]хост[:порт]][/путь][?запрос][#фрагменты]
```

Если excahnge поддерживает данный стандарт то должно сработать:

```
https://user:password@exchange.domen.local/ews/exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=mail@mail.ru&size=HR240x240
```

Если нет то надо сачала авторизироваться скриптом, а потом cookie или header с авторизацией передать с этим запросом.

Comment: данным способом к сожалению пока не получается. как только прописываю логин:пароль (или даже просто логин@exchange.domen.local) вся строка игнорируется (нет запроса аутентификации, не выгружается фотография). покопаюсь еще...